# triggers vs model updates

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a domain model with these two entities :

Parts and Contracts.

a Contract has multiple parts, and a part might belong to many contracts.

I represent it this way :

```
 class Contract 
 {
    ICollection<Part> Parts{get;set;}
    DateTime LastModifiedDate{get;set;}
 }

 class Part
 {
    ICollection<Contract> Parts{get;set;}
 }
```

Every time a Part on a contract is changed, the LastModifiedDate of the contract has to reflect the date at which the change occured.

which way is the better way to handle this  ?  :

1 -using database triggers

(this allows me to catch modifications that are made to parts without the modification having to be made through my application)

2 -or using the model in such a way that whenever a change is made at the part level, I manually change the contract's LastModifiedDate ?

3 -Is there a 3rd way that would allow to use both ways of doing things ?

4 -Is there anything else I'm missing ?

N.B : I'm using Entity Framework CTP4 for DB layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm much more familiar with NHibernate than entity-framework, but the usual way to do this is with event handling: you register a delegate to run before the object is saved and use this delegate to update the metadata.

You could create an interface named `IHasUpdatedDate` if you end up with multiple classes with such metadata. In my projects all my entities have WhenUpdated & WhenCreated fields.

It seems like entity framework does support event handling:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716714.aspx

Comment: This is actually the only one of two events available in EF but your solution works in EF as well.